# Usage of captive network

Tags: iphone, ios7

sorry for my english.
I want to do an app that use captive network. My idea is that when an user try to connect to a captive portal network the app will open instead od the relative web sheet.
I know that i have to use the function CNSetSupportedSSIDs(), but i don't understand how to implement it.
thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try already? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that i have already wrote.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SSID of my network",nil];
    bool ok = CNSetSupportedSSIDs((__bridge CFArrayRef) array);

    if(ok)
    {
        NSLog(@"completed %lu",(unsigned long)[array count]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failed");
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```